# Is there a way to get a callback when the user presses "Home" on the ShareDialog interface on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Using FB SDK 4.0, when I show a ShareDialog and then either post or cancel, the callbacks work perfectly(see code below).

The onActivityResult also captures responses accurately.

The only usage case that is not captured right now is when the user presses "home" from the native sharedialog interface once the dialog pops up. When he does that, no callback is triggered.

That's a bad user experience because I'm working on a video capture app, and the user expects the video capture to continue during the post, but would expect it to stop when he presses "home" from the share dialog pop-up.

Anyone solved this use case?

```
 shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Log.i("SHARE RESULT", String.valueOf(result));
                String postID = result.getPostId();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.i("SHARE CANCEL", "Rats!");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.i("SHARE ERROR", String.valueOf(e));

            }
        });
```

Comment: There's no way to capture the "Home" button click.

Comment: @MingLi OK and more generally is there a workaround to address the issue I'm describing?

Comment: I'm guessing that's "by design" and a security feature for Android.